# Empty template parameters to save space

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I wrote a class library in my project, and I would not use all of the classes/ functions available. Would it make any sense to write a non-template function as a template like this:

```
template<>
void doStuff(int argument)
{
     // Stuff done here
     return;
}
```

I presume that template rules might apply here, so if I didn't want to doStuff at all, and do not call that function, it would not have to be instanciated at all, would it? Can I also use this technique for classes, or is there something I didn't catch about templates?

So does this save space?

Comment: Why not create a library and leave it up to the linker to decide whether the function will be included in the final executable ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck That is more efficient, you're right, but this is just a conceptual question if this will work or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your try is a template specialization.

To have function template *without* template parameter, you may use default template parameter:

```
template<typename = void>
void doStuff(int argument)
{
     // Stuff done here
}
```

but you may instead inline it:

```
inline void doStuff(int argument)
{
     // Stuff done here
}
```

but in fact less the linker/compiler do their job and only if it becomes a problem investigate how to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you not have to name the typename?

Comment: @YannickSchrödel: As I don't use it, I don't add a name, as you may do for function: `void foo(int);`. You may use `template<typename Dummy = void>` if you find it clearer.